# Get value from integer whose name is on a string

Tags: c++, string, evaluate

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
std::string TakeFrom = "a";
```

How can I get the value from TakeFrom, in this case, a, and read the integer named like that? For example, in the code above I would have to read a's value because 'a' is what TakeFrom contains, so I'd get "1", but if TakeFrom contained "b", I'd get b's value (2).

Comment: You can't exactly, but you could use a `std::map` to map strings (variable names) to ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `a`, `b`, and `c` must stay the local `int`s, the only way you do it is the boring one, i.e. like this:

```
int val;
if (TakeFrom == "a") {
    val = a;
} else if (TakeFrom == "b") {
    val = b;
} else if (TakeFrom == "c") {
    val = c;
} else {
    // It's an error
}
```

If you are open to some changes, there are several things that you could do:

- If you are willing to "encode" the `TakeFrom`, making it an integer instead of a string (say, `0` means `a`, `1` means `b`, and `2` means `c`), you could place `a`, `b`, and `c` into an array, and use the integer `TakeFrom` as an index.
- If you are willing to allow only single-character variables, you could replace the sequence of conditionals with a single `switch`.
- If you are open to using standard collections, replace the individual variables with a map of string to integer.

Comment: Hello, sorry for late replying. Thanks for the answer. It's the most complete, and it's what I had to do.

Answer (score 1):

In normal C/C++ conditions, variable names only exist for their given scope during compilation, they are essentially human-readable mnemonics for referencing specific memory locations/registers.

C/C++ has no-to-minimal reflection capabilities, so there is no built-in way, at runtime, to reference a variable by name or look up the name of a variable by it's location/value.

To solve the problem you are describing, there are several simple options:

```
int value;
if (TakeFrom == "a") {
     value = a;
} else if (TakeFrom == "b") {
     value = b;
} ...
```

or

```
switch (TakeFrom[0]) {
    case 'a':
        value = a;
    break;
    case 'b':
        value = b;
    break;
}
```

or you could use a lookup table

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
struct Lookup {
    int&         m_variable;
    const char*  m_name;
};
static const size_t NumLookups = 3;
Lookup lookups[NumLookups] = { { a, "a" }, { b, "b" }, { c, "c" } };
for (size_t i = 0; i < NumLookups; ++i) {
    if (TakeFrom == lookups[i].m_name)
        value = lookups[i].m_variable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With there separate variables, there's no easy way (other than a series of `if` statements or equivalent).

If you turned the three variables into a single `std::map<std::string,int>`, things would be a lot easier.